# crashing on opening HomeActivity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, debugging

My app is working fine in my phone Xiaomi Redmi Note 8 pro, Redmi 7s, Redmi y2 and Samsung F41. But it crashes on startup in Samsung J7 Prime and Redmi 4. I installed it on my phone and in logcat error section, I found these errors.Kindly help me fix these errors. Waiting for your reply. Thank you.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.luteraa.luteraaesports, PID: 4956
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.luteraa.luteraaesports/com.luteraa.luteraaesports.HomeActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:699)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
    at com.luteraa.luteraaesports.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:62)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:699) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195) 
    at com.luteraa.luteraaesports.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:62) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:699) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195) 
    at com.luteraa.luteraaesports.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:62) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at com.google.android.material.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.inflateHeaderView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:222)
    at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.inflateHeaderView(NavigationView.java:387)
    at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:241)
    at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:122)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:699) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195) 
    at com.luteraa.luteraaesports.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:62) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
    at com.google.android.material.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.inflateHeaderView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:222) 
    at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.inflateHeaderView(NavigationView.java:387) 
    at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:241) 
    at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:122) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:699) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195) 
    at com.luteraa.luteraaesports.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:62) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
    at android.view.Layou
```

**XML**

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <include
            layout="@layout/contain_main"
            android:id="@+id/containMain"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/coordinator"/>

        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:itemIconTint="#F4F3C4"
            android:theme="@style/mainMenu"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
            app:menu="@menu/main_menu" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**HomeActivity**

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    BottomNavigationView navBottom;
    FloatingActionButton notFav;
    DrawerLayout drawer;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    FirebaseFirestore fStore;
    StorageReference reference;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    FirebaseUser user;
    String nameResult;

    @SuppressLint("NonConstantResourceId")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        notFav = findViewById(R.id.notificationFab);
        navBottom = findViewById(R.id.navBottom);
        drawer = findViewById(R.id.home);
        toolbar =findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        FragmentTransaction homeTrans = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        homeTrans.replace(R.id.content, new HomeFragment());
        homeTrans.commit();

        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("Invited_by", MODE_PRIVATE);
        preferences.edit().clear().apply();




//        fStore.collection("wallets").document(Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.requireNonNull(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()).getPhoneNumber()))
//                .get().addOnSuccessListener(documentSnapshot -> {
//            wallets = documentSnapshot.toObject(Wallets.class);
//            fStore.collection("wallets").document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getPhoneNumber())
//                    .update("cashCoin", updatedCash);
//        });


        toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawer,toolbar,R.string.open,R.string.close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(v -> drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START));

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(item -> {

            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.homeMenu:
                    FragmentTransaction homeTrans12 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    homeTrans12.replace(R.id.content, new HomeFragment());
                    homeTrans12.commit();
                    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                    break;
                case R.id.walletsMenu:
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WalletActivity.class));
                    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                    break;
                case R.id.referNEarnMenu:
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ReferNEarn.class));
                    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                    break;
                case R.id.myStatisticsMenu:
                    Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "stats", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                    break;
                case R.id.helpMenu:
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ContactUsActivity.class));
                    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                    break;
                case R.id.logoutMenu:
                    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                    finish();

            }
            return true;
        });

        navBottom.setOnItemSelectedListener(item -> {

            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.navHome:
                    FragmentTransaction homeTrans1 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    homeTrans1.replace(R.id.content, new HomeFragment());
                    homeTrans1.commit();
                    break;

                case R.id.navMyTournaments:
                    FragmentTransaction tournamentTrans = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    tournamentTrans.replace(R.id.content, new MyTournamentFragment());
                    tournamentTrans.commit();
                    break;

                case R.id.navMyProfile:
                    FragmentTransaction profileTrans = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    profileTrans.replace(R.id.content, new MyProfileFragment());
                    profileTrans.commit();
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        });

        notFav.setOnClickListener(v -> startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotificationActivity.class)));

        updateNavHeader();

    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
        else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.navCashWallet){
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WalletActivity.class));
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void updateNavHeader(){
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav);
        View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        ImageView imageView = headerView.findViewById(R.id.dp2);
        TextView textView = headerView.findViewById(R.id.fullName);


        reference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("uploadedImages/"+ user.getPhoneNumber());

        try {
            final File localFile = File.createTempFile("profile", "jpg");
            reference.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(localFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull @NotNull Exception e) {

                }
            });

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        fStore.collection("users").document(Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.requireNonNull(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()).getPhoneNumber()))
                .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull @NotNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.getResult().exists()){
                    nameResult = task.getResult().getString("name");

                    textView.setText(nameResult);

                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't look like the actual crash though. Where is the stacktrace from the crash?

Comment: It doesn't crashed on my phone. But it crashed in Samsung j7 prime, redmi 4 and redmi note 4.

Comment: Did you find the solution?